# A maximal invariant generates the invariant $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, group-actions, ergodic-theory, borel-sets

Let $G$ be a group action on the set $X$, and let $f:(X,\Sigma_X)\to (Y,\Sigma_Y)$ be a measurable maximal invariant ($f$ is constant on each orbit and take different values on different orbits). Am asked to show that if $(X,\Sigma_X)$ and $(Y,\Sigma_Y)$ are standard Borel then

$$\sigma(f)=\{B\in \Sigma_X:g^{-1}(B)=B \text{ for all } g \in G\}$$

The inclusion $\subset$ is easy. How can I show the other inclusion?

---

It suffices to show that for any measurable invariant (constant on each orbit) $g:(X,\Sigma_X)\to [0,1]$ there exists measurable $h:(Y,\Sigma_Y)\to [0,1]$ such that
$g=h\circ f$.

This is because we can then take $g=1_B$ so that $B=g^{-1}(1)=f^{-1}(h^{-1}(1))\in \sigma (f)$.

Any invariant function $g$ is function of $f$. But how to choose $h$ in a measurable way?

Can I use a [measurable selection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_and_Ryll-Nardzewski_measurable_selection_theorem)?

Comment: Note that if $V$ is a space with two $\sigma$-algebras $\Sigma_1,\Sigma_2$ on $V$ such that $\Sigma_1\subseteq\Sigma_2$ then the identity function is a measurable function in one direction, so if both $\Sigma_1,\Sigma_2$ are standard-Borel, then by the [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Borel_space) of standard-Borel, the identity function is an isomorphism, so $\Sigma_1=\Sigma_2$.

Comment: As a first stage I was thinking that if $G=\{1\}$ and $f$ is onto, then since $f$ is also injective, $\sigma(f)\subseteq \Sigma_X$ and both are standard-Borel so by the above, $\sigma(f)=\Sigma_X$.

Comment: As a second stage, if $G=\{1\}$ and $f$ is not onto (but still injective), then push $\Sigma_X$ to $\Sigma_{Y2}=\{f(U)\colon U\in\Sigma_X\}$ and then $\Sigma_Y\subseteq\Sigma_{Y2}$ and both are standard-Borel so equal.

Comment: That leaves the problem of dealing with $G$ and I think you need to pass to the quotient map $\tilde{f}\colon X/G\to Y$ but I don't know how to prove the quotient is standard-Borel or whether that's even true.

Comment: @ChadK I added some progress I made.

Comment: If $f$ is surjective, there is only one way to define $h$ which is to take $h(y):=g(x)$ for some $x$ such that $y=f(x)$.  This is well-defined because if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, by the property that $f$ takes different values on different orbits, it follows that $x_1,x_2$ are in the same orbit, and since $g$ is constant on orbits, $g(x_1)=g(x_2)$.  This doesn't advance proving that $h$ is measurable.   There is no actual measure involved so there's no concept of 'almost everywhere'.  You have to use standard-Borelness somehow.

Comment: @ChadK Exactly the question is how to make a measurable choice. There is a measurable selection theorem here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_and_Ryll-Nardzewski_measurable_selection_theorem. Does it apply?

Comment: This selection theorem shows that if there is a Polish topology on $X$ such that 1) All the orbits of $G$ are closed and 2) For every non-empty open $U$, the union of all orbits that $U$ intersects is in $\sigma(f)$ then there is a measurable right inverse $f_r\colon (Y,\Sigma_Y)\to (X,\Sigma_X)$ such that $f\circ f_r=1_{Y}$.  I think then you can define $h=g\circ f_r$.

Comment: @ChadK Yes but I don't see why 1,2 should be satisfied here. This is Exercise 11 from this set of notes : https://www.stat.ubc.ca/~benbr/assets/notes/stat547s-notes.pdf. I don't think it should be that difficult. Maybe am missing something.